# Running An External Program, And Several Arguments in C#

Tags: c#, external

I use the following command which should create a separate `EXE` file (`Player.exe` as an interpreter).:

```
copy / b player.exe + game.zip game.ehe
```

But, the command did not create (even if the bat file is obtained), and launches an empty `player.exe` without `game.zip`.

**My below code does not work:**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveDialog.Filter = "exe | *.exe";
    if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) ;
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = @"engine\windows\player.exe";
        info.Arguments = "/b copy " + labelPath + saveDialog.FileName;
        info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(info))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me why my code is not working as expected?

Answer (score 2):

Are there spaces in the file path that you pass? If so, you will probably want to quote the string:

```
info.Arguments = "/b copy \"" + labelPath + saveDialog.FileName + "\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if labelPath is of type Label than + will call `ToString` on it and resulting string will be something like "...Label...". You may need something like (may need to combine with Fredrik Mörk's answer if path have spaces):

```
info.Arguments = "/b copy labelPath.Text + saveDialog.FileName;
```

Comment: @user1667616, "does not work" is not an explanation of a problem. Step through the code in debugger and look at everything, make sure you are happy with values, make sure you are not eating exceptions, and post detail of such investigation in your question.